# How to create a custom element without attachShadow?

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, shadow-dom

Let's say I have some code like this:

```js
class MyElem extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    
    let templateContent = document.getElementById('template-elem').content;
    this.innerHTML = templateContent.cloneNode(true);
  }
}

window.customElements.define('my-elem', MyElem);
```

```html
<template id="template-elem">
  <div class="a">
    <div class="b">b</div>
    <div class="c">c</div>
  </div>
</template>

<my-elem></my-elem>
```

Why doesn't this work? In the Chrome inspector, the custom element has no HTML inside of it. I've also tried doing:

```
this.append(templateContent.cloneNode(true));
```

but that also resulted in an empty HTML tree.

All the tutorials mention using the shadow DOM like the following:

```
this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'}).appendChild(templateContent.cloneNode(true));
```

and while that works, it forces you to use the Shadow DOM for your custom element. Is there no way of just appending the template's HTML to your custom element without being required to use the Shadow DOM? I'd prefer to just use global CSS styling in my small use-case.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are falling into multiple traps, like everyone in their first Component adventures.

1. Custom Elements (strictly speaking only Elements **with** shadowDOM are Web Components) have lifecycle phases and Callbacks.
   This diagram: https://andyogo.github.io/custom-element-reactions-diagram/ is a **MUST** to understand.
   You want to add DOM content in the `constructor` phase; but there is no DOM Element yet in this phase.
   Only in the `connectedCallback` can DOM content be added.
   **With** shadowDOM this is another story, its "DocumentFragment" is available in the `constructor`, you can set content, But it is **not** a DOM Element yet! The `connectedCallback` tells you when your Custom Element was attached to the DOM.
2. Templates content is a DocumentFragment, but your `.innerHTML` expects a string.
   Since (in your usage) `<template>` **is** a DOM element, you can read its innerHTML (see below)

---

So, **yes** Custom Elements **without** shadowDOM are possible:

You will see the `<template>` content **twice**, demonstrating the 2 ways of adding content.

```html
<script>
  customElements.define("my-element", class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      let template = document.getElementById(this.nodeName);
      this.innerHTML = template.innerHTML;
      this.append(template.content.cloneNode(true))
    }
  })
</script>

<template id="MY-ELEMENT">
  Hello, I am an Element!
</template>

<!-- the TEMPLATE MUST exist in the DOM for <my-element> to use it! -->

<my-element></my-element>
```

---

The `constructor` is where you **prepare** your Element

This `constructor` also runs when you do `document.createElement("my-element")`.

The `connectedCallback` runs when your Element is added to the DOM

If you do not specify a method, the method from its Class parent runs, so in the above code the (default) `constructor` from HTMLElement is executed.
That is why you need `super()` in your own `constructor`... to execute the `constructor` from HTMLElement.

Note:

```js
constructor(){
 let template = document.getElementById("MY-ELEMENT").content.cloneNode(true);
 super().attachShadow({mode:"open").append(template);
}
```

is totally valid code; Google Documentation that says *"super needs to run first"* is wrong.
You need to run `super()` **before** you can **access** the Elements own scope with `this`

That is why I prefer:

```js
constructor(){

 // do anything you want here, but you can not use 'this'

 super() // Sets AND Returns 'this'
   .attachShadow({mode:"open") // both Sets AND Returns this.shadowRoot
   .innerHTML = ` ... `;
}
```

OR

```js
constructor(){

 // do anything you want here, but you can not use 'this'

 super() // Sets AND Returns 'this'
   .attachShadow({mode:"open") // both Sets AND Returns this.shadowRoot
   .append(document.getElementById(this.nodeName).content.cloneNode(true));
}
```

Note [append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) was not available in IE; so oldskool programmers won't know about its versatility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append

When your Component adventures are going to involve Class inheritance;
you call parent methods with:

```
connectedCallback(){
  super.connectedCallback()
}
```

Comment: Ah okay thanks so much! Yeah I was wondering why I could append in the constructor for shadow DOM but not regular DOM. This makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

The most simple implementation of a custom element would be:

```js
class MyComponent extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        this.innerHTML = `<div>Hello world</div>`
    }
}

customElements.define('my-component', MyComponent)
```

```css
my-component {
  display: block;
  border: 1px dotted #900
}
```

```html
<my-component></my-component>
```

However, if you don’t use Shadow DOM, you cannot encapsulate the CSS, but have to style the component through an external style sheet.

The most simple way to write a component *with* Shadow DOM would look like this:

```js
class MyOtherComponent extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: "open" })
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        this.shadow.innerHTML = `
            <style>
                :host {
                  display: block;
                  border: 1px dotted #900
                }
            </style>
            <div class="component">Hello World!</div>
        `
    }
}

customElements.define('my-other-component', MyOtherComponent)
```

```html
<my-other-component></my-other-component>
```

This way, you have a bit more overhead, but the component is truly encapsulated.